# extjs publish to local pc error could not find part of path

Tags: extjs, publish

I'm not sure what happened here but I was always able to publish to my local pc for my ExtJs project.  Now all of a sudden I am getting this error..

Error       Copying file Sencha.sencha\app\app.defaults.json to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Sencha.sencha\app\app.defaults.json failed. Could not find a part of the path 'Sencha.sencha\app\app.defaults.json'.  ExtApplication4     0

I think I did upgrade version of ExtJs a while back but not sure this is what caused it.

I also notice the files don't exist when I look at solution explorer.

[image]

Any ideas?  This is pretty vital to my whole situation.

Comment: am I not putting enough information?  what is this folder used for and is there a reason why it would be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you upgrade Sencha Cmd to 6.5x? This new version does not create the **.sencha** hidden folder anymore. You error seems to be related to this.

Comment: yes, actually, I upgraded to sencha cmd v6.5.0.180  so now that the new version doesn't use this folder how would i publish it without error

Comment: In that case, either install the same Cmd version with which the application was generated and then publish or first upgrade the application to the new Cmd version by giving command `sencha app upgrade` from the application root folder and then publish. This should work.

Comment: sorry. I'm not following. in cmd I did try sencha app upgrade.  isn't that what put me in this whole problem?

Comment: In older Cmd generated apps,  **.sencha/app** folder contained build scripts which were used by `sencha app build` command. These files could be edited to customize build targets but as this folder is not generated anymore, these files are now loaded from the Sencha Cmd install directory. Refer [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.5.1/guides/whats_new_cmd65.html). We can preserve this folder and upgrade it as before by command `sencha app upgrade --legacy`. Refer [here](https://www.sencha.com/blog/whats-new-in-ext-js-6-5-and-sencha-cmd-6-5-your-questions-answered/). Hope this helps.